# Allow Cors Origin in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am using Microsoft.ApsNetCore.Cors 2.2

> "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'exampleapi.local' from origin 'example.local' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

I set the settings with this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder =>
                {
                    builder                            
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
    });

    services.Configure<TokenSettings>(this.Configuration.GetSection("Tokens"));
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
        {
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:SecurityKey"]))
            };
        });

    services.AddMvc();
    services.Configure<LdapConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("ldap"));
    services.AddScoped<ILdapAuthenticationService, LdapAuthenticationService>();
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectMembersService, ProjectMembersService>();
    services.AddScoped<IJourneyUsersService, JourneyUsersService>();
    services.AddScoped<IProjectRolesService, ProjectRolesService>();
    services.AddScoped<IPmoGuardianService, PmoGuardianService>();
    services.AddScoped<IHolidaysService, HolidaysService>();
    services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();
    services.AddScoped<INotificationsService, NotificationsService>();
    services.AddScoped<INotificationUsersService, NotificationUsersService>();
    services.Configure<AWSConfigSes>(Configuration.GetSection("AWSSmtp"));
    services.AddDbContext<JourneyContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("JourneyConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<TSMContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TSMConnection")));
    services.AddDbContext<PmoGuardianContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PmoGuardianConnection")));

}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IMailService mail, INotificationsService not)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    Recurrence recurrency = Recurrence.GetInstance(not);
    //new TSMClockService(mail);

    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}

[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Mail")]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
```

But It doesn't work, always I got the same error

Comment: The CORS headers have to be set by the target server, not *your* server.  *They* have to give *you* access, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue with 2.2

Comment: @Christian did you have any luck figuring this out?

Comment: Not yet, I will try to do a downgrade to Cors, I hope to resolve the problem with that. And you?? @Capo

Comment: @ChristianHerrejon - this may be a shot in the dark for you, but I was able to finally get things working by adding 
<system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />..</system.webServer>
to my webconfig on my server. I updated our hosting package for core v2 as well, but this seemed to have no effect. Hopefully this will help!

Comment: @Capo I solved it, just change the web.config

Comment: @ChristianHerrejon what was the change you made?

Comment: I don't know. now my application doesn't work but 3 hours ago was working well @Capo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amy's right in her comment. CORS headers need to be set by the target server, not yours.

You will often find issues with CORS if you are trying to hook into an API on a different port but running locally on the same IP address (a most common example is localhost:<> trying to ping localhost<>, etc.).

If you are trying to run this on your local machine with Google chrome you can download the below extension which will allow you to toggle on and off the CORS rule so you can test locally:
[Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf)

Comment: Thank you. If I am on localhost, the API works fine but if I am on production, the API gets the error

Answer (score 3):

I've just lost a couple of minutes trying to figure out why CORS isn't working for requests from http://localhost:8080 that I've setup according to the official documentation.

Well it's because I added a '/' at the end of the URL. So, remove your '/' from the allowed origins.

There's even a Note on the Microsoft docs about this!

> Note: The URL must not contain a trailing slash (/). If the URL
>   terminates with /, the comparison returns false and no header is
>   returned.

Answer (score 1):

This is the exmple provided here:[ASP.NET Core 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com"));
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, 
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // Shows UseCors with named policy.
        app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
```

The finally use it like this on the controller or action:

```
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
```

Also for some reason make sure that app.UseCors is called before app.UseMVC.

Also if all you need is CORS from a single origin; you use simpler solution with no policies:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseCors(
        options => options.WithOrigins("http://example.com").AllowAnyMethod()
    );

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Comment: I tried both but It doesn't work, anyway I am grateful

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if like me you're using the `appsettings.json` file for configuration, be sure to add this:

```json
"cors": {
  "rules": [
    {
      "origin": "https://localhost:44379",
      "allow": true
    }
  ]
}
```

This simple addition made everything magically work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy way to do it.

1. Install package

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`

2. Put the code below in **startup.cs** file

`app.UseCors(options => options.AllowAnyOrigin());`